# deployed application fails with timeout

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have a Python application (windows machine) connecting to on-prem SQL-Server to fetch the data and do some python functions.
I wanted this application keeps continuously check the data periodically.
So, I kept this application in AWS-ECS and assigned the cron-job using lambda.
The problem I am facing in cloud-watch logs,

I could see the error: "timeout: invalid time interval 'm'

Answer (score 0):

I created and run my application in Windows environment in my machine. But when I deploy the code in AWS. In particularly, the application triggers with lambda its working in a Linux environment so the work directory for windows and linux path must be changed. For example:
in windows: app/foldername/.py
in Linux: src/foldername/.py

So with this small working directory issue, it fails to look the code path when Lambda trigger. That is the reason the server connection timeout error.